# WINAPI window does not work.

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I have made this GUI application using C++ and WINAPI, just after i finished my tutorial but never works whatever i try...

here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)     {

WNDCLASS window;
window.cbClsExtra = NULL;
window.cbWndExtra = NULL;
window.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
window.hCursor = LoadCursor (hInst, IDC_ARROW);
window.hIcon = NULL;
window.hInstance = hInst;
window.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
window.lpszClassName = "WINDOW";
window.lpszMenuName = NULL;
window.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

RegisterClass(&window);

HWND hwnd = CreateWindow("WINDOW", "Win32 Window Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |    WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 200, 200, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

MSG message;

while (GetMessage(&message, hwnd, 0, 0)){

TranslateMessage(&message);
DispatchMessage(&message);

}

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

switch(message){

case WM_DESTROY:
{

PostQuitMessage(0);
return 0;
break;

}
}

}
```

i tried to change nearly everything to different values and to add the header file but that never worked as well.

Comment: When you say "never works", what do you mean with that? Don't the window open? Do you get an error somewhere? Does the program crash? Please elaborate.

Comment: Pretty standard bugs, beyond never checking for errors so never being able to diagnose failure.  Your window procedure **must** call DefWindowProc() for messages that it doesn't handle itself.  Right now the WM_NCCREATE message doesn't get handled and that's the end of any attempt to get the window created.

Comment: The first thing you should do is check the result of the functions, determine if any error is occurring via whatever is stated in the documentation, and get more information if available, as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply the following changes to your source code:

1. Instruct the window to update its contents:

   ```
   ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
   UpdateWindow(hwnd);
   ```
2. Initialize the `MSG` structure, don't filter the messages, and appropriately use the return value of `GetMessage`:

   ```
   MSG message = {0};

   while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
       TranslateMessage(&message);
       DispatchMessage(&message);

   }
   ```

   Filtering messages by using the `hwnd` argument will only retrieve messages from that window's message queue. `WM_QUIT` would be lost, and since you didn't check the return value of `GetMessage` for `> 0`, your message loop would continue to spin indefinitely.
3. Pass all messages you do not handle on to `DefWindowProc`. Not doing so will prevent a window from even getting off the ground. As Hans Passant responded above, `WM_NCCREATE` is not handled, causing the call to `CreateWindow` to fail (check the return value for `NULL`). Also, do not ignore compiler warnings (as your code as posted produced):

   ```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND window,
                            UINT message,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam){
       switch(message){

       case WM_DESTROY:
           PostQuitMessage(0);
           return 0;

       default:
           break;
       }

       return DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
   }
   ```
4. Always check for errors. Any API call that can fail (refer to the documentation) should have its return value checked. In particular you need to check the calls to `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow`. The latter would have given you the clue, that something is wrong:

   ```
   if(RegisterClass(&window) == 0)
       return -1;

   // ...

   if(hwnd == NULL)
       return -1;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the end of your window procedure:

`return DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);`

Right now you are not handling any messages except WM_DESTROY. And also not returning anything from the procedure, which means undefined behavior.

Comment: i added the line in a default case in window procedure and it worked but when i click the x button it only hides but not closes, what can be the problem in this??

Comment: That is because your GetMessage only accepts window messages, and WM_QUIT is a thread message. You need to change to `GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)` as well. IInspectable's answer already explains this as well.